# X vs. X-al adjectives (asymptotic vs asymptotical, etc.)

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, morphology, ic-ical

Right now I am writing a technical report, where I describe *asymptotic(al)* [curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_curve), [expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) etc. My understanding after a bit of web browsing is that *asymptotic* and *asymptotical* are near-synonymous but the former is much more common (please correct me if I am wrong), so I will replace all instances of *asymptotical* by *asymptotic*.

Is there any general rule for those X vs. X-al situations? I can handle the most common cases (such as ["Economic" vs. "economical"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/economic-vs-economical)) because I have seen them enough times, but I have not inferred a general rule, so I am at a loss when presented with an uncommon word (such as "asymptotic").

(I am not a native speaker.)

Comment: You have to be very careful with some words: *historic* is different from *historical*. (Just as is *economic* from *economical*.) If you don't know, look up the words in a dictionary.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree in principle. However, `historic vs historical` returns thousands of relevant links in Google, whereas `asymptotic vs asymptotical` does not.

Comment: I'm not talking about Google. I'm talking about looking up the words in a dictionary. Unless Google *leads* you to an online dictionary, it's a terrible tool in general.

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are historical reasons behind the choice of the suffixes -ic - ical as explained here:

***[-ical](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ical#etymonline_v_32844)***

> compound adjectival word-forming element, usually interchangeable with -ic but sometimes with specialized sense (such as historic/historical, politic/political), Middle English, from Late Latin -icalis, from Latin -icus + -alis (see -al (1)).
>
> ***Probably it was needed because the forms in -ic often took on a noun sense*** (for example physic). Forms in -ical tend to be attested earlier in English than their twins in -ic.

(Etymonline)

Comment: So... no general rule. Well, that's English I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I have been thinking about this a lot recently and i have decided that perhaps the general rule is:

a single element is -ic, a battle is historic, a light switch is electric, 2+2=4 is arithmetic, Gandalf is Fantastic, a money saving tip is economic, a piece of logic is well, logic.

A more complex thing made of many -ic elements is -ical. a War is historical, the wiring in a whole house is electrical, a system made up of many pieces of arithmetic is arithmetical, Lord of the Rings is Fantastical, living your life following money saving tips is economical, and carrying out a task using logic is logical.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your reasoning does not hold up to scrutiny, but if you can identify a reputable reference that supports it, please [edit] the answer to include it. I strongly encurage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.