# Dragons are "fantastic" creatures or "fantastical" creatures?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, ic-ical

If I'm discussing fantasy as a genre, and I want to describe a noun as fitting that genre, should I call it *fantastic* or *fantastical?*

It seems both words exist in (say) [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fantastical), but the -al form is described as a variant.  Is it dispreferred or less common?  I fear Ngrams won't help here since "fantastic" also means "extremely good," a (likely more prevalent) meaning not shared by "fantastical."

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171509/geometric-or-geometrical ; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/usage-of-symmetrical-and-symmetric ; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical

Comment: I would only ever interpret *fantastic* as meaning "extremely good". If you used *fantastical* I would be more likely to get your meaning. I'm trying to think of an adjective which means "belonging to fantasy" but I can't think of one.

Answer (score 2):

I personally find two distinct senses for each word. If we have to pick one or the other, the one I would choose would fit in as many different ways as possible.

**fantastic**

1. great; superlative.
2. relating to, or having the qualities of, fantasy in general or one
   fantasy in particular.

*"The idea that the day the last American finally buys a gun, the whole country will turn into one big cool-headed, peace-loving family has the air of the fantastic."*

**fantastical**

1. being or relating to fantasy or some particular aspect of fantasy.
2. fantastic, but with an extra syllable for clarity or emphasis (Edit: much as people do with "ironical" [1]).

*"UFOs do not really exist, but if they did, their alien passengers would not cast magical spells. Spielberg's* E.T. *was less science fictional than it was fantastical."*

Either one could be fine. Which one works best I think depends entirely on context.

<sub>[1]: E.g., Robin Williams' character, Sean Maguire, in *[Good Will Hunting](http://www.moviescriptsandscreenplays.com/BenandMatt/goodwilltrans.html)*:</sub>

> <sub>SEAN: Why don't you come, I'll buy you a drink.</sub>  
>   <sub>LAMBEAU: The drinks at those things are free.</sub>  
>   <sub>SEAN: I know, Gerry. I was being ironical.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would use "fantastic"; but I'm not sure exactly why I prefer it in this case. One piece of data – J.K. Rowling, in addition to the Harry Potter fantasy series, has written a book about the creatures in the Harry Potter world titled "[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1408803011)," which includes a dragon, among other creatures of fantasy.

Answer (score 0):

"Dragons are fantasy creatures". Fantasy as a genre only functions in that precise form. It makes clear we are talking about a (thing) that is part of this literature. I wouldn't change a thing about it

Comment: This looks reasonable to me, but I'm specifically interested in the words "fantastic" and "fantastical," which are both "real" words according to M-W.  If not in this context, when should I use them?