# electrical equipment vs electric car

Tags: british-english, ic-ical

Both of these things run on electricity. I can't figure out why *electrical equipment* can't be  *electric equipment*?
Even after some research, I can't give the proper answer.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I don't know the answer. But there seems an inherent difference between an appliance which is driven by electricity e.g. *car, vacuum cleaner, lawn mower, hedge-trimmer*, where the adjective would be *electric*; and equipment which may be associated with the dissemination of electricity e.g *generator, transformers, fuse boxes* etc, and where speaking collectively of them, one would employ *electrical*.

Comment: If you talk about individual pieces of equipment that run on electricity they are usually referred to as 'electric'. For instance _electric drill_, _electric oven_, _electric light_ and, as you say, _electric car_. However some electrical equipment does not consume electricity, it generates, distributes, converts and measures it (for example generators, transformers, circuit breakers and meters): these are usually referred to as _electrcal equipment_. The general term is _electrical equipment_ but that includes the more specific _electric eqipment_.

Comment: @BoldBen this is a useful question, and your comment would (with a reference or two) make a useful answer! :-)

Comment: But note that while generators may be electrical equipment, they are referred to as *electric generators* when discussing the device itself.  My observation is that “electrical” means “having to do with electricity”  whereas “electric” here, means “powered by electricity” or in the generator’s case, “providing electricity”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The US legal definitions website](https://definitions.uslegal.com/e/electrical-equipment/) defines **electrical equipment** as

> any apparatus, device, integral component, or integral part used in an activity which is electrically, electronically, mechanically, or by legal prescription necessary to the process of generation, transmission, or distribution of electric energy.

There does not seem to be a formal definition of **electric equipment** but there are many devices that are described as an **electric something**. For example [electric drill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_drill), [electric car](https://www.whatcar.com/category/electric) and [electric cookers](https://www.appliancesdirect.co.uk/st/electric-cookers). The last site describes an **electric cooker** as

> Electric Cookers use electricity to power both the grill/main oven and the hobs.

Internet searches for items like **electric consumer units** or **electric transformer** do return hits but, almost universally direct to pages which describe the equipment as **electrical**.

From this we can say that, in the main, if you talk about individual pieces of equipment that run on electricity they are usually referred to as 'electric'. For instance electric drill, electric cooker, electric light and, as you say in your question, electric car. However some electrical equipment does not consume electricity, it generates, distributes, converts and measures it (for example generators, transformers, circuit breakers and meters): these are usually referred to as **electrical equipment**. The general term is **electrical equipment** but that includes the more specific **electric device**.

Comment: related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341912/difference-between-acoustic-and-acoustical "They admit they cribbed their definitions from the electric/electrical definitions in American Standard Definitions of Electrical Terms (1941)."

Answer (score -2):

You can find your answer from this: we call this kind of usage "an idiomatic phrase or an idiomatic expression"