# "Comic" vs. "comical"

Tags: word-choice, ic-ical, variants

I am confused between these words. Dictionaries say they are similar, but I vaguely remember my schoolteacher apprising me of a difference between them. I would love if someone could elucidate.

Comment: [mystic vs mystical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569565/adjective-usage-of-mystic-vs-mystical) is like [magic vs magical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215878/magic-versus-magical), [classic vs classical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48608/difference-between-classical-and-classic) and [comic vs comical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/comic-vs-comical) ?

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comical - Humorous, lighted-hearted situation or behavior inspiring amusement.

Comic - In contrast to tragic. From the point of view of the ancient Greek dramatists, tragedy had to involve the fate of a great personage, e.g. a king. Comedy on the other hand, dealt with the common people, the masses. To this day, this formula remains intact in that comedy as a form of entertainment is largely intended to appeal to the masses. The behavior of such lessor figures was felt to be amusing from the point of view of tragic figures. Hence, comical is an attribute often assigned to comic.

"The behavior of the masses is truly comical."

Comment: But this makes an arbitrary choice among the various allowable senses of 'comic'.

Answer (score 5):

Irene's, Mustafa's, and Jack's distinctions ring true, and those are indeed many of the invited inferences that cluster around these two words. There are more, and more ways to talk about them.

*Comic* occurs most often in generic terms, like *comic opera, stand-up comic, a pile of comics* (cf *a couple of comics, a pair of comics*), referring to things or events or actions or images(, etc.) that are intended to be **deliberately** funny -- to make other people laugh. It also refers to the people doing the intending and the acting, etc; and to the socioeconomic system that is implied by such artifice. It's ***Artificial***, not natural.

*Comical*, on the other hand, seems to refer exclusively to amusing ***Natural*** things, etc. Stuff that really happens; shit my dad says. I don't think they need to be *ludicrous* or *absurd*; those are extremes on the humor spectrum. Even gentle irony can make one laugh sometimes. I agree, though, that excess absurdity or boffo ludicrosity often makes the laugh bigger.

When it's natural, anyway. But **not** when it's obviously contrived, which seems to be the point.

That said, I'm afraid the bad news is that this generalization does not generalize to other such pairs. The *-ic/-ical* [derivational suffix](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Derivation-Inflection.pdf), which derives an overt adjective from a noun (or from something else; it's a sloppy affix), appears mostly with [*-ic* (10,903 words)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ic.txt), but also often with [*-ical* (2,619 words)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ical.txt).

Most (but not all) of the *-ical* words appear also in the *-ic* list. And there isn't  much, if indeed any, systematic pattern visible to me from a desultory inspection of the isolated word lists. But maybe there is one.  Anyway, there they are; data is always preferable to speculation.

(By the way, these lists were extracted from a "wordlist.txt" file that was the spellchecker dictionary on the University of Michigan faculty email system for a couple of decades. As explained [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/unixlanguage.pdf))

Comment: I think that "natural things" is a spurious distinction. My guess is that anything called a [comic/comical coincidence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comic+coincidence%2Ccomical+coincidence&year_start=1940&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3) probably isn't deliberate/artificial. But *comic* still occurs more often. I reckon it's just ignorant people thinking that "longer word" = "more of whatever it's supposed to mean".

Comment: Certainly the straightforward MORE is MORE strategy doesn't work well here; but it often does, and it's never discarded, once discovered. People use whatever interpretive strategies they can figure out, and some of them work. Some of the time. With some people. That's enough to reinforce a habit pretty strongly.

Answer (score 3):

There's no inherent difference between the two words themselves, but it's important to note the two broad shades of meaning - *relating to humour* and *funny (ha-ha)*.

In terms of actual usage, *comic* is far more common in general parlance today for both senses, but some people may think the longer form *comical* is somehow more "emphatic" for *very amusing*.

Also note that there are certain "stock terms" such as *comic writer/comic actor* which imply the first meaning above. It's always possible that if you met someone thus described, they wouldn't say or do anything particularly funny (when they're not "at work"). If you ever did hear of someone described as a *comical actor*, you'd probably expect him to be more consistently funny.

Comment: You're not supposed to see anything comical on TV, for instance. What a strange system...

Comment: @John Lawler: Well, I see it's true there are hardly any references to *comical programs* on TV. But there aren't many *comic programs* either - presumably because we've done the standard "adjectivisation of noun" trick, so they're mostly *comedy programs* anyway.

Comment: Yeah. When the going gets funny, the words change fast. Everything is timing, as they tell me.

Comment: @John Lawler: Nah. Word order matters too - see [Everything is timing,Timing is everything](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Everything+is+timing%2CTiming+is+everything&year_start=1700&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Personally, I prefer [Timing is all](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Timing+is+everything%2CTiming+is+all&year_start=1940&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but it looks like I'm behind the times on that one!

Comment: Remind me to tell you the joke about the greatest Drog comedian in the world.

Comment: @John Lawler: Consider yourself reminded. I don't know *drog*, but I suppose you being US, maybe it's your version of *drogue* - which I think is some kind of windsock. And I don't know *any* windsock jokes, let alone the greatest one in the world! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2395/discussion-between-john-lawler-and-fumblefingers)

Comment: @John Lawler: Is it too soon to remind you again to tell me the joke about the greatest Drog comedian in the world? :)

Comment: Well, chat can't find the page, so I spose it may be.

Comment: @John Lawler: So, you still owe me one joke! I shall remind you again in another couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

You characterise something as **comic** when you want to say that it is funny. A comic monologue, for example, is meant to make the audience laugh. This word is used especially to talk about writing and drama or things that are funny in a deliberate and theatrical way. It is not used to describe people (except for *comic writers*).

**Comical**, on the other hand, is again something funny, but in a ludicrous or absurd way. A series of comical misunderstandings, for example, make you laugh because they don't look like they could really be happening, yet they are.

Comment: I disagree that *comic* isn't normally used of "people". In fact, *comic person* occurs [slightly more often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comical+person%2Ccomic+person&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *comical person* in NGrams.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Taking a brief look at your link, **comic person** appears in reference to literature characters or in contrast with **tragic**, pertaining again to drama and literature. I'd use **comic figure** too, referring to a character in a play or film, but I wouldn't use it to characterise real people who are funny, unless they are theatrically so, which is the essence of my definition of **comic**.

Comment: I don't understand your distinction. It seems to me *comic* has always had a broader range of meaning, specifically including "pertaining to comedy", whereas *comical* is more restricted to specific things/events/people being *amusing to others*. Your point about "not usually used of people" simply reflects the fact that people who are consistently and deliberately amusing to others are likely to be called *comics* in the noun sense.

Comment: But this does not reference all the various allowable senses of 'comic'.

Answer (score 1):

**Comic** is connected with comedy and refers to "a characteristics". 
**Comical** usually have a sense of "fun" as a result of "strange" and/or "unusual" happenings or situations.

Comment: But this makes an arbitrary choice among the various allowable senses of 'comic'.