# "Hierarchical" vs. "hierarchic"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, programming, ic-ical

When do you use *hierarchical* and when *hierarchic*?

For example, *hierarchical database* sounds much more native to me, even as a non-native English speaker. But why isn't it *hierarchic database*?

**Edit:** I just realized there are more words this question applies to: *acyclical/acyclic, aesthetical/aesthetic, cosmetical/cosmetic,...*

Comment: I hesitate to answer because I wonder the same thing, but it seems to me that hierarchic pertains more to human organizational structure, whereas hierarchical is a generic adjective.  I am probably wrong.

Comment: Regarding your edit, see [this canonical question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical) with two excellent answers. For particular word pairs, see our [dedicated tag "ic-ical"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic-ical), which I am also adding to your question.

Comment: I don't think your other examples work. Aesthetic and cosmetic are the common usage.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Very interesting read, thanks! Now that I'm seeing how many questions are tagged with this, I wonder myself how I couldn't stumble over one of them.
If you transform your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: The two suffixes _-ic_ and _-ical_ are identical in meaning and can often both apply to the same word. The morpheme is usually just called _-ic/-ical_. [This link gives more info](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57069/15299).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every single dictionary link I found redirects *hierarchic* to *hierarchical*. It seems as though there is absolutely no distinction between the meanings of two words and *hierarchical* is vastly preferred. [NGram data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hierarchic%2Chierarchical&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chierarchic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chierarchical%3B%2Cc0) fully supports this preference.

Therefore, always use *hierarchical*.

As for *why* it is *hierarchical* and not *hierarchic*, please see the previously linked question and answer: [Why is it “geometric” but “theoretical”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6581/6006)

Answer (score -1):

Hierarchic is the less commonly used adjective of hierarchy. Hierarchy is the system of organization, thus it is a noun. Hierarchical is also an adjective form of the base word hierarchy. It is used to modify the subject (organization, system etc.). In other words, we more commonly use the word hierarchical to inform the reader that the subject is a organized system of tiers, or levels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything  to the previous answer, which says hierarchical is vastly more common.