#  “Golden crown” vs. “gold crown”

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes

In case of the need to describe the color of a crown which is shown as part of an image, which is correct: a *golden crown*, or a *gold crown*?

Is it important if it is made of gold or not, but the color is gold?

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most gold crowns are golden, but not all golden crowns are made of gold.

Answer (score 6):

It seems they’re largely interchangeable. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 35 records for *gold crown* and 29 for *golden crown*. The figures for the British National Corpus are 8 and 6. The Oxford English Dictionary, however, has 6 citations for *gold crown* and 10 for *golden crown*. [This nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gold%20crown,%20golden%20crown&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows an earlier preference for *golden crown*, but with little difference apparent from about 1960 onwards.

A coin, rather than royal headwear, will, I suspect, generally be a *gold crown* rather than a *golden crown*.

Comment: @tchrist: Indeed. I possess several.

Comment: I've seen it both ways, but in some [older writing](http://books.google.com/books?id=3L-mh6mJcagC&pg=PA683&lpg=PA683&dq=%22five+golden+crowns%22&source=bl&ots=qvxvRYtGSy&sig=QCHCp4MR0rbkvCKdYIU4v6xyrJw&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%22five%20golden%20crowns%22&f=false) "golden" seems to be how they liked to describe coins.

Answer (score 3):

The *Collins Cobuild Dictionary* shows two meanings for *golden*:

1. Something that is **golden** is bright yellow in colour. (ADJ)
2. Golden things are **made of gold**. (ADJ)

While they may appear to be fungible, people who choose their words carefully would probably use *gold* to indicate *made of gold* and *golden* to indicate *bright yellow in colour*.

Elvis Presley sang “Wooden Heart (*Muss I Den*)” in the 1960 movie *G.I. Blues*. Here are two relevant lines:

- *’Cause I’m not made of wood*
- *And I don’t have a wooden heart*

They suggest that even with the *‑en* ending, it means “made of wood”, which it wouldn’t in a sentence like “He delivered a *wooden* performance on opening night.”

*Collins Cobuild* says “**Wooden** objects are made of wood”. I agree that that’s how people use it, whether literally (e.g., *wooden table* and *wooden chair*) as well as figuratively (*wooden performance*).

But unlike when *wood* and *wooden* are used literally, I don’t think that *golden* and *gold* are fungible like that. They’re only sometimes synonyms, which means that they **aren’t always interchangeable**, merely **largely interchangeable**.  A *golden crown* is not necessarily a crown made of gold, just a crown the color of gold. But a *gold crown* is necessarily a crown made of gold.

However, because there is something called “[white gold](http://www.jewelrygenius.com/RoseWhRv.html)”, an alloy of gold and nickel and which sometimes contains palladium or zinc, a *gold crown* isn't necessarily yellow. Context should tell the reader or listener whether *golden* or *gold* is being used literally or metaphorically.

Comment: I agree with the downvoter. If somebody talks about a "gold Cadillac", it will almost certainly not be made of gold. For that, you have to say [solid gold Cadillac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Solid_Gold_Cadillac). Google returns tons of hits for "gold Cadillac Deville" and very few for "golden Cadillac Deville"; *gold* is a color as well as a metal.

Comment: Good point, Peter, but I don't believe I or the OP mentioned a "gold Cadillac", just a "gold crown". When talking about cars, one normally thinks color names refer to the paint and not the material or status (idiomatic usage): a blue Ford isn't sad, a red Ford isn't angry, a yellow Ford isn't cowardly, a green Ford isn't envious, and a rainbow Ford is surely multicolored and not homosexual or otherwise culturally diverse. A "gold crown", OTOH, is ambiguous unless context indicates color or material. But this distinction is important only to those who care about the words they use.

Comment: Verbose answers are of grate value, including your answer, but sometimes there is a shorter answer that pinpoints the idea avoiding irrelevant issues. I read all answers and comments and decided to use: `a golden crown`. As I specifically asked, I need to make a description of the color of a presented crown image. I came into a conclusion that for the color description requirement it is not important if the crown is made of gold or not. Thank you for your grate answer, you've got my upvote.