# "Magic" versus "magical"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, ic-ical

Two-part question. We say ***magic** wand* and ***magical** creature*, and swapping the adjectives sound wrong, even if they are technically right.

1. Are there rules about which one to use, or is this a classic "use whatever sounds right" situation?
2. Can anyone explain how a single adjective comes to be "modified" like this depending on context? Is there a linguistic term for this?

Comment: I don't know enough linguistics to answer the second part, so I'm just writing this as a comment. This seems to be a "use whatever sounds right" scenario as you observed. Apart from your examples, it's always "*magic* square", "*magical* thinking" and "a *magical* evening".

Comment: This [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#Use_of_noun_adjuncts_when_an_adjectivally_inflected_alternative_is_available) is all I could find, and suggests that it's a case of whatever sounds right.

Comment: The OED does not make clear when to use *magic* and when *magical*. But there are one or two pointers. Where the meaning is the secondary one of 'beautiful or delightful in a way that seems removed from everyday life' then it has to me *magical* e.g. *a magical evening*. Where it refers literally to magic, one does not seem to use *magical* unless it is 'relating to, using, or resembling *magic*. For everyday magicians' kit, *magic* seems to apply.

Comment: I can see no reason to call the swapped version “definitely wrong”.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6581/9368

Comment: [mystic vs mystical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569565/adjective-usage-of-mystic-vs-mystical) is like [magic vs magical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215878/magic-versus-magical), [classic vs classical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48608/difference-between-classical-and-classic) and [comic vs comical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57060/comic-vs-comical) ?

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Comment: Because "magic" is a noun and can also be used as an adjective, its occurrence in a statement like "It's magic" cannot be unambiguously understood as an adjective or a noun. If you want to be unambiguously using an adjective, I would recommend saying that something is "magical".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think with careful speakers/writers, explicitly structurally adjectival  ***magical*** is usually reserved for *metaphoric* usages, whereas ***magic*** tends to be more *literally* to do with the "supernatural". So if I were considering the utterances of a *careful* speaker, I would expect this distinction...

> 1: *"You should read this magic book"*  (it's a book about magic)
>    2: *"You should read this magical book"* (reading it will be a metaphorically enchanting experience)

Note that where the referent is something that *often* occurs with the "noun-used-as-adjective" form (such as *magic trick, lamp, beans, spell, wand*, etc.) it usually carries a sense that the target noun *has supernatural powers*. My careful writer could imply that his book actually had supernatural powers in *speech* (by placing very heavy stress on the word *magic*), but in writing it would require rephrasing or help from context to disambiguate that third possible sense.

I suspect that (particularly in casual speech) there may be a tendency to use the shorter adjectival form more often, simply because the "more appropriate" full version sounds a bit [highfalutin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highfalutin).

Having said that, there are plenty of established collocations where no literal reference to the supernatural is implied by the short form *(magic square, lantern)*, and some that almost defy categorisation *(magic marker, bullet)*. Those are the ones you just have to learn to get used to.

Comment: +1 for the magic/magical book example, and a metaphysical +1 for the bit about using the shorter adjective.

Comment: @txteclipse: I can imagine the young Harry Potter boasting to a [Muggle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muggle) child: *"Your magic wand is just a toy, but mine's a **magic** magic wand!"*

Comment: Your ability to clarify the English language is amazing. It's magic!

Comment: On a minor point, it's interesting that the online Merriam-Webster *only* recognizes the spelling *highfalutin*, not *highfaluting* or even the intermediate *highfalutin'*.

Comment: @Erik Kowal: I would have included the apostrophe if I'd had to type it myself, but it was all cut & paste! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, we software developers have been contributing to the problem. "Magic code" is code that runs "behind the scenes" without being explicitly invoked, "magic numbers" are numbers that appear directly in source code and [don't make any sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code), a "magic cookie" is a security token, etc.  Nobody ever uses "magical" on a noun in this industry, oddly enough.

Comment: @Kevin: If the current somewhat flippant use of "magic" had been commonplace half a century ago, the ["shut up and calculate"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentalism) faction within the world of theoretical physicists would have referred to ***magic equations***. But magick had a bad press back then.

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Comment: @BCLC: Depends what you mean by "like". I can't imagine what "metaphorical" ***mystic/al, comic/al*** might mean, so it makes no sense to suggest the explicitly adjectival ***comical*** is more likely to be used metaphorically. But it ***is*** true that a ***gold ring*** is more likely to be *literally* made of gold, whereas a ***golden ring*** might just have the colour / appearance of gold. And your ***wood fire*** literally burns real wood, but a ***wooden smile*** is just metaphor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh right. i guess. thanks!

Comment: "magic" not only refers to the supernatural but also to conjuring/stage magic, hence magic show, magic trick, magic wand, magic box, etc. Presumably the connection is with supernatural magic. (The word "Magick" is sometimes used for supernatural magic, especially by practitioners, to distinguish from stage magic.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between magic and magical.

- **magic** (*adjective*) ~ 1. *pertaining* to magic (n.); *used* in magic (n.); *having the power of* magic (n.); as, **"a magic wand"** and 2. producing extraordinary results, as if *by* magic (*noun*) or supernatural means.
- **magical** (*adjective*) ~ magic (especially in sense 2 of **magic** (*adj.*), defined above): used *predicatively* as well as *attributively*, whereas **magic** (*adj.*) tends to be attributive alone.

(*Webster's New 20th C. Dictionary, Unabridged, 2nd Ed.*, c.1959)

So, both words may be used attributively, but only **magical** may be used [predicatively](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/attributive-and-predicative-adjectives).

Comment: "Magic" is often used predicatively, especially in the weakened slang sense meaning amazing/great: "You're magic", "This is magic". Maybe this is more recent than 1959.

Answer (score 2):

A number of usage commentators have visited the questions of whether and to what extent *magic* and *magical* differ as adjectives.  The earliest reference work I have found that addresses these questions is Frank Vizetelly, [*The Practical Standard Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SccsAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA690&dq=The+adjective+magic+is+applied+more+commonly+to+the+powers&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9357b3e7yAhUeFjQIHdk6CnYQ6AEwAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=The%20adjective%20magic%20is%20applied%20more%20commonly%20to%20the%20powers&f=false) (1922):

> **magic,** *a[dj]* **1.** Of the nature of magic; used in magic; possessing supernatural powers; sorcerous. **2.** Magical. **3.** Acting like magic. ...
>
> **magical** *a[dj]* Pertaining to or produced by magic. Syn[onym]: magic. The adjective *magic* is applied more commonly to the powers, influences, or practices, while *magical* is more frequently used of the effects of magic; we speak of *magic* arts, a *magic* wand, but of *magical* effect, a *magical* result; the *magic* art of Circe produced *magical* transformations of her victims. In many cases the choice between the two words is determined by euphony, or, in poetry by meter.

A more detailed discussion appears in Henry Fowler, [*Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hrtIDakUpA4C&pg=PA338&dq=%22magic(al)+adjectives%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq3uKJ3O3yAhWMJzQIHYlaCK8Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22magic(al)%20adjectives%22&f=false) (1926):

> **magic(al),** adjectives. ... *Magic* tends to lose those adjective uses that cannot be viewed as mere attributive uses of the noun. That is, first, it is very seldom used predicatively ; *the effect was magical* (never *magic*) ; *the ring must be magical* (not *magic*, though *must be a magic one* is better than *magical one*). And, secondly, the chief non-predicative use is in assigning a thing to the domain of magic (*a magic ring*, *carpet*, *spell*, *crystal* ; *the magic art*), or in distinguishing it from others & so helping its identification (magic lantern, square), rather than in giving its characteristics descriptively (*with magical speed* ; *what a magical transformation*) ; this second differentiation, however, is not yet strictly observed.

Fowler thus observes (in 1926) a situation in which use of *magic* as a predicate modifier and where attributive use typically doesn't extend to "giving [a thing's] characteristics descriptively." Evidently, Fowler expects general descriptive usage of "magic" as an adjective to become more strictly observed in the future than at the time of his writing.

Notably, Ernest Gowers's revised edition of *Modern English Usage* (1965) retains the first edition's wording verbatim, except that it omits the final nine words ("this second differentiation, however, is not yet strictly observed"). Presumably, Gowers feels that (as of 1965) the situation has resolved itself as Fowler had predicted and strict observation of the second distinction now prevails.

Other writers have made similar claims. For example Bergen Evans & Cornelia Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1956) offers this assessment:

> **magic; magical.** Of the two adjectives, *magical* is the more versatile, sine it can be used to describe attributes or characteristics (*a magical transformation*) and to stand predicatively (*The reaction was magical*). *Magic*, on the other hand, is now used chiefly to identify (*magic lantern*, *Magic Flute*).

Harry Shaw, *Dictionary of Problem Words and Expressions* (1975) says this:

> **magic, magical.** As a noun, *magic* refers to producing results through mysterious influenceor unexplained powers. It involves the control by persons skilled in magic or supernatural agencies and the forces of nature. In view of this meaning, *magic* seems loosely used and overused to refer to occurrences that might correctly be labeled "unusual," "effective," or "spectacular." "His piano playing was *magic*" and "When she smiled the effect was *magic*" are examples of such misuses of a powerfully charged word. As an adjective, *magic* means much the same as *magical*, but here again exaggeration is usually apparent: The lovers spent a *magical* (or *magic*) night" and "This baritone has a *magic* (or *magical*) range to his voice" are examples of overemphasis. Recommendation: use both adjectives sparingly and always place *magic* before the word it modifies: "*magic* number," "*magic* square," "*magic* lantern," "*magic* artistry." If this can't be done, use *magical*.

George Davidson, [*Chambers Pocket Guide to Good English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TdNNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22carpet.+Magical+on+the+other+hand%22&dq=%22carpet.+Magical+on+the+other+hand%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8hIyJ4u3yAhUPHzQIHZLyCmoQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg) (1985) [combined snippets, but not the complete entry] has this description:

> **magic, magical** The adjective **magic** generally means 'pertaining to magic': *a magic wand*; *He rode on a magic carpet*. **Magical** on the other hand, means  'as if caused by magic , enchanting', as in *It was a magical experience* ; *a magical change of character*. ...

Merriam-Webster, *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (1989) cites several of the preceding sources and then offers its own assessment of the magic(al) landscape:

> **magic, magical** According to Fowler 1026 the distinguishing features of *magic* and *magical* are that (1) *magic* is almost always used attributively and (2) *magic* is used literally and in fixed phrases while *magical* is used with extended meaning. Shaw 1975 objects to figurative uses of *magic* and *magical* because he believes they are overused; he also advises using *magical* when *magic* cannot be used attributively. Chambers [that is, Davidson] 1985 assigns literal uses to *magic* and figurative uses to *magical*. We agree to some extent with Fowler and Shaw but disagree with Chambers. Here is what we found in the evidence we have collected.
>
> The adjective *magic* is almost exclusively an attributive adjective, partly because the word *magic* after a linking verb can be construed either as a noun or an adjective. *Magical* can be either attributive or a predicate adjective, but attributive uses are about three times as common as the others. So nonattributive uses of either word are relatively uncommon. Attributive uses that are part of fixed phrases (as *magic carpet*, *magic square*, and *magic number*) call for *magic*, not *magical*.
>
> Both words are used with literal force to refer to the supernatural [Examples omitted.] And both are commonly used with extended meanings, though their connotations may differ. *Magic* often implies some kind of instant effect, while *magical* often involves a feeling such as enchantment. These are only tendencies, however, because the figurative uses of the two words overlap quite  bit.

Kenneth Wilson, [*The Columbia Guide to Standard American English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l9g3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&dq=generally+means+pertaining+to+magic:+a+magic+wand+figurative&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ7eHe2O7yAhVkFjQIHXuMAZ8Q6AEwAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1993) suggests that there is very little separation between how the two words are used as modifiers:

> **magic** (*adj. n.*), **magical** (*adj.*) *Magic* is primarily an attributive adjective (*a magic box*), but both *magic* and *magical* can appear in predicate use, *magical* clearly as predicate adjective and *magic* as either that or a predicate nominative: *Her sudden appearance was magic* {*magical*}. We use both words literally (*a magic wand*, *a magical top hat*) and figuratively (*It was a magic moment*; *His hold on the audience was magical*).

Compared to the other usage commentaries mentioned here, Michael Swan, *Practical English Usage*, second edition (1995) offers coverage that is broad and general to the point of limited usefulness:

> ***magic*** and ***magical*** *Magic* is the more common word, and is used in a number of fixed expressions. [Examples:] *a **magic** wand* (= *a magician's stick*) | *the **magic** word* | *a **magic** carpet*
>
> *Magical* is sometimes used instead of *magic*, especially in metaphorical senses like 'mysterious', 'wonderful' or 'exciting'. [Example:] *It was a **magical** experience.*

As a side note, I find it interesting that Swann doesn't use the Oxford comma, even though the book is published by Oxford University Press.

Martin Manser, [*Good Word Guide: The Fast Way to Correct English - Spelling, Punctuation, Grammar and Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=F_2J500M_3YC&pg=PT266&dq=%22The+adjective+magic+is+more+closely+related+to+the+art+or+practice+of+magic+than+magical%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW5PGI6e7yAhULJzQIHew8Bq4Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22The%20adjective%20magic%20is%20more%20closely%20related%20to%20the%20art%20or%20practice%20of%20magic%20than%20magical%22&f=false), fifth edition (2003) offers a more detailed assessment of the two words:

> **magic** or **magical**? The adjective *magic* is more closely related to the art or practice of magic than *magical*, which is used in the wider sense of 'enchanting' | *a magic wand* | *a magic potion* | *a magic spell* | *a magical experience* | *the magical world of make-believe*.
>
> The two adjectives are virtually interchangeable in many contexts, although *magic* is retained in certain fixed expressions such as: | *magic carpet* | *magic lantern*, etc., and *magical* is sometimes preferred for things that happen as if by magic: | *a magical transformation*. *Magic*, but not *magical*, is also used in informal contexts to mean 'wonderful': | *The holiday was magic!*

I have no idea what information Manser was relying on for that last observation, but a Google Books search finds just one confirmed match (other than Manser's own book for "[holiday was magic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22holiday+was+magic%22&hl=en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLqUXTGC4b5dM8wvlElkTKPqbU-mw%3A1631085512919&ei=yGM4Yc3KN6zP0PEPrPi4oA8&oq=%22holiday+was+magic%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..33i299k1l3.2907.3034.0.4673.2.2.0.0.0.0.71.133.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.131....0.Gg2sPhFWYL0)"—"[That cycling holiday was magic for me and Elsie...](https://books.google.com/books?id=S5qYDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&dq=%22holiday+was+magic%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipsNrN7e7yAhWJJjQIHQQCDTIQ6AEwAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22holiday%20was%20magic%22&f=false)" (2016)—but seven for "[holiday was magical](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22holiday+was+magical%22)" over the years 1982–2017 (not counting a 2001 instance of "To me, Billie Holiday was magical").

Simon Heffer, [*Simply English: An A to Z of Avoidable Errors*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7WOEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA205&dq=magic,+magical+The+adjective+magic+literal&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizwdOC3-7yAhUxOn0KHTIaDnEQ6AEwBXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=magic%2C%20magical%20The%20adjective%20magic%20literal&f=false) (2014) resuscitates Davidson's argument that the difference in usage between the two terms is that magic applies to literal situations magical to figurative ones:

> **Magic** and **magical** A *magic* moment is when something illusory or supernatural appears to have happened. A *magical* moment is when it is quire obvious that something illusory or supernatural has not happened, but the ambience of the occasion could cause one to think that it might. The adjective in *-ic* is literal; the one in *-ical* metaphorical, suggesting that something has the properties or likeness of magic. The dictionary defines *magical* as 'of or relating to magic' in the first definition, but a second one, almost as old and now more idiomatic, is 'resembling magic in action or effect; enchanting'.

This is precisely the component of Davidson's treatment of the two words that *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* flatly rejected back in 1989.

For truly in-depth coverage of how English speakers and writers use *magic* and *magical*, easily the most impressive source I came across was Mark Kaunisto, [*Variation and Change in the Lexicon: A Corpus-Based Analysis of Adjectives in English Ending in* -ic *and* -ical](https://books.google.com/books?id=TObzDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA230&dq=%22magic+or+magical%22+adjective&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJy_Gv1O3yAhX_JzQIHSFLBtkQ6AEwAnoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22magic%20or%20magical%22%20adjective&f=false) (2007). Kaunisto devotes a 30-page chapter, titled "From Supernatural Powers to Exciting Football Games: *Magic/Magical*," to the word pair in question. He begins by observing that magic and magical seems to invite a greater level of caution among prescriptivist commentators than most other differentiable *-ic/-cal* adjective pairs do:

> Although *magic/magical* is usually listed among those *-ic/-ical* pairs subject to semantic differentiation, it is also that pair among the ones studied with which writers of usage manuals tend to lean towards descriptivism rather than taking a firm prescriptivist stance. It is this adjective pair that writers of usage manuals would most readily admit as showing a degree of semantic overlap, even interchangeability, of the two forms, while maintaining that more or less clear distinctions of usage can nevertheless be perceived. As with other *-ic/-ical* pairs in present-day English, one can find instances of slips or inconsistencies in the use of *magic* and *magical* by one and the same writer, ...

Ultimately, Kaunisto seems to be inclined to interpret the difference in usage between *magic* and *magical* as following roughly along the lines of the difference in usage between *electric* and *electrical*:

> It would seem that the semantic aspects of the collocating words play a role in the choice of the adjective: the more "remote" words representing the classifying sense 'having to do with magic', e.g. *knowledge*, appear more often with *magical*, whereas the words denoting more "immediate", concrete or visible things, such as actions of conjuring or enchanted objects, tend to select the shorter form of the adjective. In phrases denoting the idea of the phenomenon itself, *magical* is used more often, which contrasts with the assumption that a closer semantic connection with the basic or original sense of the adjective would generally show as a preference for the *-ic* form. It can be argued then that the selection of either magic or magical according to the head word follows the lines of concrete versus abstract or immediate versus remote. As was seen earlier, such a distinction could also be seen to some extent with the pair *electric/electrical*, where the longer form is preferred ion senses with a more remote connection with electricity, as in *electrical engineering*. In the sense 'powered by electricity', the selection of the adjective was governed by the head word through an opposition of specific versus general (*electric kettle* vs. *electrical appliances*). This type of drastic distinction, however, cannot be observed in the case of magic/magical with head words such as *artefacts*, *items*, *objects*, etc., with which both forms are found in the material studied, in spite of the head word clearly signifying concrete things[.]

Kaunisto devotes considerable space to instances of *magic/magical* as a synonym for *enchanting*, *wonderful*, *excellent*, and *special*. When used for this purpose, the two words seem to be very nearly interchangeable, especially in British English. Kaunisto also provides a couple of interesting charts—one consisting of adjective occurrences of *magic* and *magical* in Literature Online for the years 1850–1903, in which *magic* appears 178 times and *magical* 64 times, and the other consisting of adjective occurrences of the same two words in the *[London] Daily Telegraph* during 1995, in which magic appears 277 times and magical 280 times. Clearly, magical things are happening at about the same rate as magic things these days—and the great majority of the *magical* instances in 1995 involved situations where the adjective was used to signify (according to Kaunisto's assessment) "'enchantingly beautiful', 'wonderful' 'thrilling'"; in this subcategory of usage the tally was 45 for *magic* and 196 for *magical*, up from 16 for *magic* and 11 for *magical* in the 1850–1903 period.

Kaunisto's conclusion is worth considering, too:

> Considering the results concerning the use of the adjectives in the corpora in general, there is perhaps less interchangeability today than one would expect from the comments referred to in the introductory paragraphs of this chapter. One feature that is often stressed in usage manuals is the "freer" or less restricted use of *magical* in both attributive and predicative positions in the sentence. When one examines the numbers of predicative uses of *magic* and *magical*, a difference in favour of *magical* can be observed, but the difference is perhaps not as striking as one would have expected. This itself may not be entirely surprising, because usage manuals have a tendency to pay attention to questions of acceptability, which are not necessarily directly reflected in actual frequencies of use.
>
> As far as possible future developments in the use of *magic/magical* are concerned, perhaps the most crucial meaning where changes are likely is the descriptive sense 'enchanting'. The notion of approval, which is increasingly signalled through the word *magic*, may be linked more closely to the use of both adjective forms in this sense. Given the direction of change in most semantically differentiated *-ic/-ical* pairs, one might assume that *magic* eventually becomes the more frequent form in the descriptive sense as well, as in the case of *electric/electrical*, and that the choice between the two forms will be governed even more strongly by the collocating words.

According to this assessment, although *magical* has made tremendous headway against *magic* on the "enchantingly beautiful/wonderful/thrilling" front since the early 1900s, *magic* is likely to become more and more common in both predicate positions and attributive positions where the adjective is functions figuratively or descriptively. Someday, language and usage mavens may come to recognize how far ahead of his time Ben E. King was when he sang (back in 1960) about "[This Magic Moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYrjZlK2o0)."

Answer (score 0):

It is a case where you can use whichever adjective sounds correct to you. Some of these phrases like *magical creature* have become more idiomatic. So it sounds *slightly* strange to native English speakers, if you use phrases like *magic creature*. The adjective suffix *-al* means "relating to".  In this case, for the word *magical*, it means relating to magic.  The linguistic term for these *-al* suffixed adjectives would be [derivation (Source: Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28linguistics%29), but there's not any grammatical rules that require the derived versus the non derived adjective.

The word *magic* in the term *magic wand* is what's called a [noun adjunct (Source:Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). A noun adjunct lets you use *magic* as an adjective instead of a noun. Using *magic* or *magical* is acceptable but usually people choose the phrasing that is already the most commonly used.

Comment: No; I've just checked in six online dictionaries, and each lists 'magic' as having achieved full denominal (here, adjectival) status. Both 'magic' and 'magical' mean 'relating to magic'. But you're right about a polarisation having taken place with regard to which variant to use where.

Answer (score 0):

While in my mind they are mostly interchangeable, I might see differing usage based on the properties of the item.  I would expect "magical" to be used for any item that was created through the use of magic whether or not the item can actually actively do/preform magic or simply has passive supernatural properties.  I would expect "magic" to be reserved for items that are able to actively perform/do things.  For instance, I believe a wand could be described either way, while a centaur I would describe as a magical creature unless it was able to actively cast spells or had some sort of specific power that would make it a magic (using) creature.

Please excuse the highly fantasy fiction slant of my answer; it seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The chronology of **magic**(n.), **magic**(adj,) and **magical**(adj) is as follows

The noun, in its meaning of the (i) use of rituals to influence the course of events or to manipulate something (ii) an instance of magic or (iii) a magical charm or object (countable and now obsolete) first appeared in English around the end of the 14th century.

> c1387–95   G. Chaucer Canterbury Tales Prol. 416   *He kepte his pacient a ful greet deel In houres by his magik natureel.*

> c1395   G. Chaucer Squire's Tale 218   *It is rather lyk An apparence ymaad by som magyk.*

> 1811   H. M. Brackenridge Jrnl. 18 June in Views Louisiana (1814) 257   *On these occasions, each one suspends his private magic on a high pole before his door.*

The adjective **magic** - of or relating to magic or of something that uses magic or works or is produced by magic.

> a1393   J. Gower Confessio Amantis (Fairf.) v. 3947   *Jason..upon Medea made him bold, Of art magique, which sche couthe.*

> 1968   Brit. Jrnl. Psychiatry 114 964/2   *Magic incantations, recipes and actions,..are openly used today in Lucania against fascinazione, malocchio, fattura and similar spells.*

but was not used predicatively.

The use was with physical objects does not appear to have arisen until the 17th century

> [OED]**Of a material object: used or usable in magic rites, having (or apparently having) supernatural powers, under the influence of magic. Also (frequently in magic glass, magic mirror) applied to objects in which future events or distant places may be seen; often figurative.**

> 1621   G. Sandys' translation of Ovid First Five Books. Metamorphosis i. 25   *Then, silent, with his Magick rod he strokes Their languisht lights, which sounder sleep provokes.*

> 1992   Times Higher Education Supplement. 27 Mar. 34/5   *As Thomas concludes, everyone who looks in the Newmanian magic mirror finds there a reflection of himself.*

**Magical** adj. did not enter the language until the late 15th century, and stems from Magic + -al, where the suffix -al is from classical Latin -ālis, an adjectival suffix, ‘of the kind of, relating to’

OED

> **Magical** adj.
>
> 1.a. Of or relating to magic; = magic adj. 1a.
>
> a1492   W. Caxton's translation of Vitas Patrum (1495) i. clviii. f. clxiv/2   *To ouercome hym as a Dysceyuour and begyler in ouercomynge his Magycall argumentacyons [Fr. magiques argumentacions].*
>
> 1665   J. Glanvill Sciri Tuum: Authors Defense 35 in Scepsis Scientifica   *Those strange operations are not Mechanical but Magical.*
>
> 1938   R. G. Collingwood Principles of Art i. 10   I need not here go into the reasons which have led archaeologists to decide that the purpose was magical.

It doesn't seem to be the case that magical was introduced for predicative use, as it wasn't  until the mid 17th century that an example occurs, and is otherwise exceptionally similar in meaning (although not application) to "magic".

Conclusion:

**Magic**(adj.), adapted from the noun, seems to have the nuance of **possessing or being 'magic'**, i.e. which the noun uses itself or which may be used by an agent/possessor), whereas **magical** is a little vaguer - **associated in some way** with magic - the strength and nature of the association will be indicated by the context.

But the telling line from the OED is "Of or relating to magic; = magic adj."