# 'Magic Tree' or 'Magical Tree': When to use, which is more common?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm struggling to find an answer to my question, which is about the difference between  ***Magic Tree*** and ***Magical Tree***

For native English speakers, is there a preferable option that "sounds right"?

If that's not the case, and there *is* a rule, when should I use each of them?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215878/magic-versus-magical

Comment: A non authoritative opinion: A MAGIC tree should be a tree pertaining to the conjuring arts (or some imitation there of). A MAGICAL tree might be MAGIC but it may just be hyperbolically wonderful.
`Yesterday was magical and today is wonderful` means aren't we having a nice time, `Yesterday was magic and today is wonder` is a student at hogwarts describing their timetable.