# Gold or golden nugget?

Tags: expressions

I can't figure it out. I've seen both been used, but a nugget is presumably gold, or can golden be used as well?

Comment: From Google Books: [goose that laid the golden egg](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22goose+that+laid+the+golden+egg%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):208000 hits, [goose that laid the gold egg](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22goose+that+laid+the+gold+egg%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):21. But [gold engagement ring](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gold+engagement+ring%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):1370 hits, [golden engagement ring](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golden+engagement+ring%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):48.

Comment: An egg will hatch somewhere in the future, hence it contains a fetus, i.e. it's not entirely gold. Is that why the goose laid the "golden" egg, rather than the "gold" egg?

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?

Answer (score 3):

Both meanings overlap, but not perfectly.

"Golden nugget" is ambiguous. It isn't clear if you mean that the nugget is made of gold, or if the nugget is golden in color.

"Gold nugget" indicates that the nugget is made of gold.

Comment: It's nowhere near that clear-cut. Countless millions of kids [get a gold star](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+a+gold+star%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) for good quality schoolwork, but practically *none* of them would actually be made of gold.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's not clear-cut for the word _gold(en)_ in general, but it's pretty clear-cut when _nugget_ is added. A _golden nugget_ could turn out to be pyrite. A _gold nugget_ is, or should be, composed of gold.

Comment: To the extent that legal society informs language, in the US (and maybe other countries) there are regulations about the use of the term *gold* when applied to metals. That doesn't mean common parlance will follow those rules.

Comment: @phenry: I think it would be more reasonable to classify *gold nugget* as a "fixed phrase" (which we all expect to mean *a nugget of gold*). Given that the ***precise opposite*** occurs with the goose's *golden egg* referenced in my comment to the question, I don't see that one example as relevant to the general case.

Comment: @bib: Are you seriously suggesting the US has legal definitions about what can and can't be described as a ***gold ring***? That seem unlikely (and totally unenforceable) to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers By and large (a nautical term having nothing to do with jewelry), yes. See [this regulation](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=5d77ce5206e62baabca2c8edc2791490&ty=HTML&h=L&r=PART&n=16y1.0.1.2.13#16:1.0.1.2.13.0.5.5). This is directed to commercial practice. The GPs (Gold Police) rarely break in on intimate moments when a swain is exaggerating the purity of the proffered token of affection.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And there is rarely an investigation to see if the Fifth Day of Christmas is being fraudulently caroled.

Comment: @bib: I don't know for sure, but it seems to me because *pure* gold is so soft, there aren't actually many things made of it apart from Krugerands. I think in practice that legislation doesn't *directly* legislate about the actual use of the word. It's just a question of whether or not *in context* a customer might reasonably claim to have been "misled".

Comment: ...As to the GP busting in on a deceitful swain trying to palm off a mere 18-carat ring as "gold", I'm put in mind of Ben (Seth Rogen) in [Knocked Up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478311/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) offering an empty box (to be filled with a gold ring when he can afford it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15384/discussion-between-bib-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: are [gold/en and wood/en](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/433757) like [mystic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569565), [classic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48608), [magic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215878), [comic/al](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57060)?