# How to distinguish 'technique' and 'technology'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives

Also, how should I decide when to use *classic* and when to use *classical*?
What is the difference between these terms with regard to how they are used?
Should I use 'classic music' or 'classical music'? 'Historic event' or 'historical event'?

Comment: Can you clarify this, it is rather vague, what are you actually asking?

Comment: ***Technique vs Technology*** -  http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-technique-and-vs-technology/

Comment: You have two questions here, neither of which is especially well fleshed out. But in any case I think you should devote one question entirely to _technique_ and _technology_, and then write up a separate question (on its own page) that asks about _classic_ versus _classical_. They're completely different questions.

Comment: Actually—no. You should drop your question about _classic_ vs. _classical_ altogether and instead refer to this EL&U question: [Difference between "classical" and "classic"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48608/difference-between-classical-and-classic).

Comment: My advice is to look at the link that Josh61 provides above, and then either withdraw your question (if that discussion answers your question satisfactorily) or replace the current body of your question with an explanation of why that discussion isn't satisfactory. Either way, you need to get rid of the _classic/classical_ content in your question, because it only confuses the issue—and does so in a way that is likely to lead to the closing of your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question in the body (about _classical_ and _classic_) is a duplicate of an earlier EL&U question, and because the question in the header and the question in the body are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really all this required was a quick google; *'classic vs classical'* returns a [Grammarist article](http://grammarist.com/usage/classic-classical/) from which I now quote:

> **Classical** has a few narrow definitions, including (1) of or relating to the ancient Greeks or Romans, (2) of or relating to a peak stage of a civilization, and (3) of or relating to European orchestral music of the late 18th and early 19th centuries. These aren’t the only definitions of classical. What’s important is that the term usually relates to fairly well-defined historical periods of culture and science.
>
> **Classic** is broader. Its main adjectival definitions are (1) of lasting significance or worth, (2) typical, and (3) adhering to established standards of elegance or restraint. As a noun, it means an enduring work, and as a plural, with the (and usually capitalized—the Classics), it refers to the literature of ancient Greece and Rome.
>
> **Examples**
>
> You may remember Carter as a Hall of Fame catcher for the Expos and
> Mets and a signature player in the classic 1986 World Series. [Los
> Angeles Times]
>
> Russell Maliphant’s new work opens, appropriately enough given the
> artist who inspired it, like a fin de siècle fantasy of classical
> Greece. [Evening Standard]
>
> Alba teamed the black and turquoise frock with opaque tights, classic
> black heels and a white and black clutch bag. [Stuff.co.nz]
>
> El Sistema, Venezuela’s program[me] of social uplift through classical music, has received more attention over the last few years. [New York Times]

*['Technique vs technology'](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-technique-and-vs-technology/)* returns very much the same sort of thing:

> While technique is a way of doing a thing or activity, technology is a word used to refer to complex processes and principles of science used in gadgets and appliances.
>
> **Technique**
>
> Two players playing table tennis and following the same rules and making use of the same equipment such as a racquet and a ball can seem to be playing with contrasting styles. Their styles are dependent upon the techniques of holding the bats and making strokes […] style of playing or doing the same thing differently is called a technique.
>
> **Technology**
>
> Technology is a word that is used to refer to scientific principles and complex processes that go inside a gadget or appliance. We talk about computer technology, communication technology (to refer to progress that has been made in recent times), medical technology, and so on.