# When does the "historic/historical" in "historic/historical records" refer to the documents or to the events?

Tags: word-usage

After checking many Web sites, I found much inconsistency in whether "historic records" or "historical records" is used.

- Which of these terms simply means "a document, created at any time, which describes the past"?
- Which of these terms means "a document of much significance, itself considered an important part of history"?
- Which of the terms means "a document of much significance in itself, which also contains descriptions of prior events"?

[Why is it "geometric" but "theoretical"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical) describes the meaning of the "-ical" ending found in "historical", but I could not see how to determine its usage in this confusing context.

Answer (score 1):

For many purposes, *historic/historical* are interchangeable, but as a general rule...

> [historical records](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get%20behind%20the%20mule%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22historical%20records%22&oq=%22historical%20records%22&gs_l=serp.3..0.14476.15300.1.15696.2.2.0.0.0.0.51.100.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.QHZYO9BAoyo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.d2k&fp=fe4c2fbde0fda570&biw=1274&bih=930) usually means *accounts written around the time of the events they describe*.

Probably most instances of [historic records](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get%20behind%20the%20mule%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22historic%20records%22&oq=%22historic%20records%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i13.771247.771429.2.771660.2.2.0.0.0.0.124.180.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.ipBujNmVWdQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.d2k&fp=fe4c2fbde0fda570&biw=1274&bih=930) (which is maybe 40 times less common) have exactly the same meaning. But here are a few hundred instances of [his historic record](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get%20behind%20the%20mule%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22his%20historic%20record%22&oq=%22his%20historic%20record%22&gs_l=serp.3...264493.267950.3.268199.5.5.0.0.0.1.135.414.3j2.5.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab._BRoVV7X1yM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48340889,d.d2k&fp=fe4c2fbde0fda570&biw=1274&bih=930), which in nearly every case have nothing to do with either accords *or* history (they're ***remarkable*** achievements). From that, one could feasibly make out a case for saying *historic records* might sometimes be used to distinguish *important accounts* from *historical* ones, but I couldn't endorse such a usage.

Since even the above distinction isn't really supported by English, it's no surprise I don't think any inflected version of the word *history* would cover OP's third sense of "both of the above".