# What is the difference between "graphic" and "graphical" as adjectives?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology, ic-ical

Are the two adjectives completely interchangeable, or is there a distinction between them?

Does it matter which I choose?

Comment: Could you use 'supplementary content' instead and avoid the confusion altogether?

Comment: @mjsqu Wouldn't "supplementary" then become completely redundant, since I'm saying, essentially, that it should supplement rather than replace?

Comment: I advise that you use *graphical.*  *Graphic* has had the misfortune of acquiring a second meaning, usually that something is bloody, gory, and violent; i.e. graphically explicit.

Comment: While I appreciate the advice on which word to use (and I agree with the reasoning given), I would still like to know if there is a distinction in meaning, aside from the ambiguity of "graphic".

Comment: Possibly, I guess you could remove the adjective altogether, just say 'other content'. Or, 'pictorial'? Anyway, I agree with @user61979 and your original point, "graphical" is better than "graphic".

Comment: The noun form is _graphics_, often spelled _grafix_ to difference it from pre-internet conventional categories. Why use a noun phrase with a dubious adjective suffix  -- _-ic_ and _-ical_ have a long history, and are often interchangeable; they're cited together as _-ic(al)_ -- when there's a handily ambiguous noun ready to do the job?

Comment: Somewhat related, the canonical question: [Why is it “geometric” but “theoretical”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Great link. That was a very informative read. I'm now wondering if this should be closed as a dup; while the answers on the linked question don't explicitly address whether there is a distinction between "graphic" and "graphical", it provides enough information to suggest that if there isn't a fairly clear distinction, then yes, they can be used interchagably.

Comment: @Beofett well, as the answers there demonstrate, there is no one-size-fits-all explanation for all things *-ic* vs. *-ical*, which is why we keep the [ic-ical](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic-ical) tag around for all the individual words.

Answer (score 4):

As an adjective 'graphic' refers more directly to the actual process of drawing, or the discipline that has evolved from what used to involve training one how to draw.  But 'graphical' refers less directly to drawing as a process, but to the visual result.

As a noun, all depictions are 'graphics', whether drawn or projected.

'Graphic' also has the meaning of 'so vivid you cannot avoid seeing it', as in graphic sex or violence.  So people occasionally avoid using it when it can be taken in that sense.  (Donkey Kong eating Princess Peach would be graphical violence, but not graphic violence.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very technical meaning which might illustrate one of the norms that Wilson mentioned. In mathematics, a *graph* is a representation of objects where some pairs of objects are connected by links. The adjective form of *graph*, in this sense, *must be* **graphical**.

So to say that a probabilistic model can be represented as a graph, where the objects are random variables and the random variables can be connected by links which represent their dependencies, is just like saying that a probabilistic model can be represented as a **graphical model**. You cannot use *graphic model* in this context. (I have heard people say *graph model*, although that sounds jarring to me)

Comment: Would you say "graphic representation of a temporal sequence" or  "graphical representation of a temporal sequence"?

Answer (score 1):

**Graphic**

- Nowadays, the word **graphic** is widely used as a noun to refer to an image that is generated by a computer.
- As an adjective it used to mean the following:

  - Written, drawn or engraved as in "graphic symbols";
  - Of or relating to the graphic arts as in "the graphic works of the Inca";
  - Relating to or presented by a graph as in "a graphic presentation of students' scores";
  - Evoking lifelike images within the mind as in "a graphic description of house";
  - Giving a detailed description  of nudity or sexual activity as in " a graphic narration of what he/she did with her/him in bed.

**Graphical** is used  adjective and not as a noun. It is used mainly to mean:

- Relating to or presented by a graph as in "a graphical presentation of students' scores";
- Written, drawn or engraved as in "graphical symbols".

It can be said that "**graphic** is wider in meaning than **graphical**.

Comment: Would you say "graphic representation of a temporal sequence" or  "graphical representation of a temporal sequence"?

Answer (score 0):

As adjectives, graphic and graphical are equivalent. Graphic is also a noun, as in a visual graphic, whereas graphical is only an adjective.

However, there are phrases where graphic is conventionally used, other phrases where graphical is the norm. Therefore, it's important to choose the correct word for a given situation.

For example:

> graphic arts,
>   graphic equalizer,
>   graphic novel[s],
>   graphic artist[s],
>   graphics card[s],
>   graphic designer[s]
>
> flowcharts are graphical presentations,
>   graphical user interface

Comment: So, um. *Graphic* and *graphical* are not equivalent, after all. Indeed, it would be impossible for them to be equivalent due to [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(linguistics)).

Comment: They have equivalent meanings, but there are idioms and set phrases that happen to use just one or the other.