# Rule for suffix to describe where someone is from

Tags: suffixes

Is there a rule or pattern to describe where someone comes from?

Some examples of places, with the word to describe people from that place:

- New York / New Yorker
- London / Londoner
- Toronto / Torontonian
- Paris / Parisian
- Boston / Bostonian
- Brazil / Brazilian
- Mexico / Mexican
- Vancouver / Vancouverite

There are -er suffixes, -ian suffixes, -an suffixes, and -ite suffixes. Possibly others that I could remember.

Is there a general rule for determining which suffix to use when you see the name of a place for the first time?

Comment: Relevant, and possible dupe: [Is there a rule for which suffix to use when creating adjectives from nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/is-there-a-rule-for-which-suffix-to-use-when-creating-adjectives-from-nouns?rq=1)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151556/nationalities-when-do-we-use-the-singular-or-plural-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules for forming demonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61765/rules-for-forming-demonyms) (A demonym is a word describing a person from a particular place.)

Comment: Liverpudlian, Harrovian, Muscovite. No 'rule'. You have to learn them.

Comment: Glasgow natives are Glaswegians, it seems.

Comment: @StuartF: Yes, and it seems there is no strict rule.